# Build object where one field depends on the other

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, lombok

I want to build an object where one of my class field depends on the other. Somewhat like

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class MyModel {

    @DynamoDBHashkey
    private String key = encrypt(value1, value2);

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String value1;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String value2;
 }
 
 
MyModel model = MyModel.builder()
     .value1(1002020)
     .value2(1384818)
     .build();
```

Now when I do `model.key()` I want to be able to retrieve this value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm missing something but you could just add getter. According to documentation [Annotation Type DynamoDBHashKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBHashKey.html)

> Annotation for marking a property as the hash key for a modeled class. Applied to the getter method or the class field for a hash key property.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyModel {
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String value1;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String value2;

    @DynamoDBHashkey
    public String getKey() {
      return encrypt(value1, value2);
    }
 }
```

Comment: The key is my partition key, so I will need to annotate it with @DynamoDBHashKey. Just updated the question for clarity :)

Comment: You could apply this annotation to getter as well “Annotation for marking a property as the hash key for a modeled class. Applied to the getter method or the class field for a hash key property”